# Save & New Button for Visualforce page with data on lookup

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, lookup

```
public class ProductController {

    ApexPages.standardController m_sc = null;

    public ProductController(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
    m_sc = sc;
    }

    public Pagereference doSaveAndNew()
      {
        SObject so = m_sc.getRecord();
        upsert so;

        string s = '/' + ('' + so.get('Id')).subString(0, 3) + '/e?';
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.Info, s));
        return new Pagereference(s);
      }

}
```

This is my controller. The Save & New is functioning well but I need to include the value on the lookup when it reloads.

[image]

Comment: Good question. URL hacking doesn't seem to work as nicely in a Visualforce page.

Comment: the normal pattern for this is to set a PageReference variable to the VF page, use the `getParameters().put(paramName,paramVal)` to pass values, call `setRedirect(true)` and then, when the constructor of the new page is called, default the values you need doing any necessary soql. The new page will display with values defaulted